# How do I properly convert a UTF-8 encoded char array to a Go string when using a C-library in Go?

Tags: utf-8, go, parallels, cgo

I'm trying to use a C library in Go. The `C.PrlFoundVmInfo_GetName` function writes a UTF-8 encoded string into **name** with length **nBufSize**.

```go
// PRL_CHAR sName[1024];
var sName [1024]C.PRL_CHAR
// PRL_UINT32 nBufSize = sizeof(sName);
var nBufSize C.PRL_UINT32 = C.PRL_UINT32(unsafe.Sizeof(sName))
ret = C.PrlFoundVmInfo_GetName(hFoundVmInfo, (*C.PRL_CHAR)(unsafe.Pointer(&sName)), &nBufSize)
// printf("VM name: %s\n", sName);
var gName string = C.GoString((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&sName)))
fmt.Printf("VM %d name: \"%s\"\n", nBufSize, gName)
```

What is the proper way to declare **name** (and **nBufSize**) and how do i convert **name** to a Go *string*? The above code dosen't work as I expect. It prints:

```
VM 1024 name: ""
...
```

#### C API Documentation, extract

PrlFoundVmInfo_GetName - Parameters

```c
PRL_RESULT PrlFoundVmInfo_GetName(
  PRL_HANDLE handle, 
  PRL_STR sName, 
  PRL_UINT32_PTR pnNameBufLength
);
```

- **handle** - A handle of type PHT_FOUND_VM_INFO identifying the container.
- **sName** - [out] A pointer to a buffer that receives the name. Pass a null pointer to determine the required buffer size.
- **pnNameBufLength** - [in] The size of the buffer used to receive the output data (in bytes). [out] The required buffer size if the buffer parameter contains a null pointer or if the specified buffer size is not large enough.

The full documentation is available at [C API Documentation - PrlFoundVmInfo_GetName](http://download.parallels.com/doc/psbm/v5/rtm/Parallels_C_API_Reference/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=PrlFoundVmInfo_GetName@PRL_HANDLE@PRL_STR@PRL_UINT32_PTR.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution, create a byte array and make **sName** point to it. When it has been used use `C.GoStringN` to convert the content to a Go string.

```go
var buf = make([]byte, 1024)
var sName C.PRL_STR = (C.PRL_STR)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf))
var nBufSize C.PRL_UINT32 = 1024
ret = C.PrlFoundVmInfo_GetName(*hFoundVmInfo, sName, &nBufSize)
gName := C.GoStringN((*_Ctype_char)(unsafe.Pointer(sName)), C.int(nBufSize))
fmt.Printf("VM %d name: \"%s\"\n", nBufSize, gName)
```

Answer (score 3):

> [Command cgo](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)
>
> [Go references to C](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Go_references_to_C)
>
> A few special functions convert between Go and C types by making
>   copies of the data. In pseudo-Go definitions:
>
> ```
> // C string, length to Go string
> func C.GoStringN(*C.char, C.int) string
> ```

[The Go Blog: C? Go? Cgo!](http://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo)

Comment: I did Google before posting, but I can't get my head around the creating a buffer for the output parameter that should contain the name.